# regular expression to match first first three letters of a string that must be 12 chars long and uppercase

Tags: php, regex

I need some pointers with some regex voodoo - I just don't use them enough day to day to be familiar with them.

I'm processing a string containing multiple words and need to look for a reference number.

The ref number is in the format **LCSYK89HE4W4** . 'LCS' is always constant, the Ref is always 12 chars long. The rest of the ref is made up from random uppercase alphanumeric chars.

Examples:

```
LCSJKIIU786T
LCS5YU87TFR4
LCSKIJ5R67DE
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following regex

```
LCS[0-9A-Z]{9}
```

Using this string however, it happens that a line containing additional characters before and after will not be rejected. If the string should begin and end with the ref number, use

```
^LCS[0-9A-Z]{9}$
```

You can test the regex here http://phpregextester.com/ (use `/LCS[0-9A-Z]{9}/`)

Comment: Hi there Commusoft - thanks for the reply. It's not quite there as I need to parse a sentence - so there will be many words. The nearest that I've got so fat is `code`/(?=\b\w{12}\b)\b\w{0}LCS\w*\b/`code` - but this doesn't lock it down to only uppercase alpha numerics. Nearly....

Comment: This works perfectly /\bMBS[0-9A-Z]{9}\b/ . Thanks heaps Commusoft that pointed me in the right direction.